# SUMO Traffic modeling: How to create network with lefthand drive rule?

Tags: xml, sumo

I am a new user of SUMO traffic simulator. I know how to create road-network, but I have no idea how to shift the network from right-hand drive to left-hand drive.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to SUMO's netconvert, so you can for instance simply call

```
netconvert --lefthand --osm-files city.osm
```

for getting a left hand network.

Answer (score 0):

If you create/edit your road networks in NETEDIT it is also quite simple. In the NETEDIT GUI, navigate to Processing>Options>Processing, scroll down and tick the `lefthand` checkbox.